# Step over in Eclipse is entering every method

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I've installed JadClipse plugin in eclipse for decompiling and now the `Step Over` option in debug mode is entering every method. I don't know why is happening, but maybe someone can help. Unninstalling the plugin did not solve the problem.

Comment: what happens on `Step into`?

Comment: If uninstalling the plugin didn't help, then some Eclipse settings have probably been changed.

Comment: `Step into` does the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

Just go to :

Window -> Preferences

Then Expand General and Select keys.

Search by Step and check how are your keys assigned.

Comment: The keys are as they should, `F5` and `F6`. Also clicking the icons on debug window is doing the same thing...thanks anyway

Comment: Try running eclipse like this: eclipse -clean

Answer (score 0):

I think @Ricardo has the right idea. Check if there are other functions also mapped to the F6 key. This can cause this problem as well.

Comment: When I use the button is the same. The key is only mapped to `Step over`.

Comment: Check the Error view and see if JADClipse is breaking something